# Linq outer join and group by with count in select

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, database, linq

I have this SQL statement

```
SELECT 
    users.UserName, COUNT(photos.Id) AS 'photos' 
FROM photos 
RIGHT JOIN users ON photos.UploaderId = users.Id 
GROUP BY users.UserName`
```

I try to build this linq query

```
    protected void LinqDataSource1_Selecting(object sender, LinqDataSourceSelectEventArgs e)
    {
        var appContext = new ApplicationDbContext();
        var x = from u in appContext.Users
                join p in appContext.Photos on u equals p.Uploader into ps
                from sp in ps.DefaultIfEmpty()
                group ps by u into g
                select new { Username = g.Key.UserName, Photos = g.Count() };
        e.Result = x;
    }
```

but I get all users with no photos with 1 returned from `Count()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is to be expected, as there is no group that would have a `Count` of 0 (because in that case the group wouldn't exist in the first place).

You'll need to modify your group selector to ensure that the resulting count takes into account the fact that a photo could be null. This is slightly tricker than in SQL, since value-typed columns (like an int) will have default values instead of null. You'll need to check by either comparing a non-nullable string column to null (as I do below, since I assume `Uploader` is not nullable) or you'll have to compare a non-nullable column against an impossible value (say, comparing an identity column to a value outside of its range, perhaps -1).

```
select new 
{ 
    Username = g.Key.UserName, 
    Photos = g.Where(i => i.Uploader != null).Count() 
};
```

Comment: just what i wanted. Thanks! PS: it's i.Uploader!=null

Comment: Good catch; corrected. If this answered your question, please don't forget to click the check mark to accept it.